# Altering Oracle table: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, alter

Using Oracle Application Express for Oracle 11g

Adding a foreign key constraint to a preexisting table.

**Table: COMMUNICATION**

```
COMMUNICATION-ID      NUMBER        
COMMUNICATIONTYPE_ID  VARCHAR2(6)   
CONTACT_ID            NUMBER         
COMMUNICATIONVALUE    VARCHAR2(40)
```

**Table: COMMUNICATIONTYPE**

`COMMUNICATIONTYPE-ID  VARCHAR2(6)`

---

Using the following SQL in the SQL Command Interface

```
ALTER TABLE COMMUNICATION
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_COMMUNICATIONTYPE
FOREIGN KEY (COMMUNICATIONTYPE_ID)
REFERENCES COMMUNICATIONTYPE(COMMUNICATIONTYPE-ID)
```

Returns the following:

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Didn't think this could be any simpler. What on earth could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the field is called `COMMUNICATIONTYPE-ID`?

`-` is not normally used in identifiers as it has special meaning.

If I were you I would rename the column `COMMUNICATIONTYPE_ID`

To use it in an identifier you need to always surround that identifier in double quotes.

```
ALTER TABLE COMMUNICATION
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_COMMUNICATIONTYPE
FOREIGN KEY (COMMUNICATIONTYPE_ID)
REFERENCES COMMUNICATIONTYPE("COMMUNICATIONTYPE-ID")
```

Comment: Double-quoted identifiers are an abombination to all right-thinking peole.

Comment: Oh okay. I seem to have given every primary key in my database invalid identifiers.

So no symbol other than underscore is allowed in Oracle naming conventions? (I think hash and tilde can technically be used but are discouraged)

Comment: @Duncan - [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm) agree with you (number 7 in that list).

Comment: @Duncan I recommend using only uppercase letters (A-Z) and underscore `_` in identifiers. Note that unquoted identifiers are automatically converted to uppercase in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

`COMMUNICATIONTYPE(COMMUNICATIONTYPE-ID)`

Dash is not valid in Oracle names.  I think you meant to type an underscore.  It's easily done.

As the DDL for the COMMUNICATION table the same typo that `create table` script may have failed as well.  So the error could have been thrown in more than one place.